# How to combine Python Application with QT C++ Application

Tags: python, c++, qt, qml

I currently try to develop an Application which is separated in a C++ QT/QML GUI Part and a Python Daemon Part both communicate over zeromq and should be delivered as one application. Since I am relatively new to C++ I would kindly asked if the solution how I would combine them is suitable or if there are better ways to structure this.

My Cmake File currently would look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project([project-name] VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /Users/[username]/repos/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)



set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter REQUIRED)

if(DEFINED ENV{VIRTUAL_ENV} OR DEFINED ENV{CONDA_PREFIX})
  set(_pip_args)
else()
  set(_pip_args "--user")
endif()

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ondoki-daemon
  GIT_REPOSITORY    "https://[token]@github.com/repo/repo.git"
  GIT_TAG           develop
  SOURCE_DIR        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/[project-name]"

  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""

)

execute_process(COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} -m pip install -r ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/[repo-name]/requirements.txt)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(ZeroMQ CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(cppzmq CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS  )
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS filesystem regex REQUIRED)
find_package(msgpack CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        qml.qrc
        images.qrc
        python.qrc
        zmqbridge.cpp
        zmqbridge.h
        zmqworker.h
        zmqworker.cpp
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable([project-name]
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET [project-name] APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library([project-name] SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable([project-name]
          ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_compile_definitions([project-name]
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries([project-name]
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick
  protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite libzmq
          libzmq-static  nlohmann_json nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
          cppzmq cppzmq-static ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
          msgpackc msgpackc-cxx ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} 

  )

set_target_properties([project-name] PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_import_qml_plugins(project-name)
    qt_finalize_executable(project-name)
endif()
```

Things which will of course be changed are putting vars into relative paths , hiding tokens with secrets and generally structure CMake into multiple files and libs. This is not the question here and rather the general approach of including a Python Project.

In the next step I would add all Python files to a python qrc and call them from the C++ Application via something similar to this.

main.cpp

```
#include "zmqbridge.h"
#include <Python.h>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<ZMQBridge>("ZMQBridge", 1, 0, "ZMQBridge");

    std::cout << "C++ program started!\n";

    char filename[] = "main.py"; // qrc:repo/main.py something like this 
    FILE *fp;

    Py_Initialize();

    fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);

    Py_Finalize();

    std::cout << "C++ program is ending!\n";
    return 0;

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/src/gui/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Again  of course not plain stupid from main --> Just for showcase

The CPP side has then a ZEROMQ Dealer which sends messages to a ZEROMQ Router + Dealer Construct and communicates back with the QML Application ...which works flawlessly and has a lot of advantages but where I as mentioned struggle is to find the best approach combining them two. The above solution works of course but I am not sure this is something a seasoned C++ developer would choose , so any help or hints into the right direction would be of great help. Thank you ...

Comment: What are you asking ? You have two very different parts in your software, actually implemented using different programming languages. You need some intra-process communication, and you chose 0MQ for that. What is the problem with that ? You could put them in two different processes (still communicating through ZMQ), but that would not change much.

Comment: There is no problem in that , my question is regarding delivering both programs via ExternalProject_Add and packing all files in a qrc file or if there is a better approach to do that

Comment: You may want to check out PythonQt: https://mevislab.github.io/pythonqt/ This allows you to embed Python in a Qt application (vs. pyside which embeds Qt in Python). When it's embedded, it reduces a lot of the complexity of packaging and IPC.

Comment: Thank you but there are multiple reasons not to use pyside or the probably dying pyqt , one is complete separation of GUI and Backend and independence of QT as a company and packaging as one protected application ...there are packaging variants with python but they are far from optimal solution and the application uses python to be replaced on a later point which is rather hard with an intervened application based only on pyside